# How to remove png image white background color using php?

Tags: php, image-processing, png

I have to remove image background color and make that transparent. I am using below code to make image transparent but that is not working.

```
function transparent_background($filename, $color) 
{
    $img = imagecreatefrompng('image.png'); //or whatever loading function you need
    $colors = explode(',', $color);
    $remove = imagecolorallocate($img, $colors[0], $colors[1], $colors[2]);
    imagecolortransparent($img, $remove);
    imagepng($img, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$filename);
}

transparent_background('logo_100x100.png', '255,255,255');
```

Please see screenshot for better understanding that what I am trying to do.

[image]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `but that is not working.` **What** isn't working? Is there an error? does the file not save? does the color not get removed? does a new color get added? does the image get distorted? Does the picture of a bobcat turn into a dog? **What** isn't working?

Comment: Since it probably has a large color pallet, is it possible that white isn't pure white? Maybe you need to clear all shades of white. (create a tolerance of varying shades of white)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual color inside the box (around puma's face) is not 255:255:255 its 252:254:251. at least for most of it.

I set that color as input to your function "transparent_background" and set HTML   background color to maroon color, result is 
http://www.photojoiner.net/view/?fid=LpEajVuDhXT7yqH6WBBuhJtT0m9I4NnY.jpeg

You can create a loop and try making range of colors transparent. ie from 251:251:251 to 255:255:255. Not sure about the perfomance though.

Just giving you a wiled idea since your screenshot shows a web browser assuming its a web application, you can do the same using HTML5 context, You can select a region on the canvas and edit its imageData on that region. I.e select the white square with puma and set alpha setting of all white (or range of colors) pixels' to 0. More reading on HTML5 canvas pixel manipulation https://dev.opera.com/articles/html5-canvas-basics/#pixelbasedmanipulation